# htaccess redirect domain to new domain specifc page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I use a pointer to redirect a old domain to the new domain.
But I want to redirect them to a specific page.

How can achieve that? My current code still redirects to the homepage:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^olddomain.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.newdomain.com/page/ [R=301,L]
```

Also tried this, but that does not load the page, because to many redirects

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !olddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/page/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Make this rule as your first rule and use a new browser for testing.

Comment: @anubhava That's what I already tried, but it still redirects to the homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com/page/? [R=301,L]

# rest of your rules go here
```

Trailing `?` in target URI is required to strip off any previous query string.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Tried that, but it still redirects to the homepage.

Comment: It was a browser cache issue. Works fine, thanks a lot!